# How to fix the error: bad signature 0x00000000 index file corrupt

Tags: git

I have not been able to update my repository because I'm getting this error below when I commit the project.

I have been told to remove the `index file` and run these commands `del .git\index`and
`git reset` however there no `index file` in my project file (see below my project file)

Any idea how can I fix this error?

**error**

```
9:44 AM Commit failed with error
                0 files committed, 13 files failed to commit: Jobly Version 1.0
                Jobly Version 1.1
                Jobly Version 2.0
                Jobly Version 2.1
                bad signature 0x00000000
                index file corrupt
```

**my project folder**
I cannot see the `index.file`

[image]

[image]

Comment: The index file is in the `.git` directory.  Did you run those commands from a CMD shell like you were told to?  You won't be able to do it from within your editor.

Comment: I was told to run those commands after removing the index file but as I cannot find that file, no I have not run any commands, can you advise what is the process to fix this? not sure where is the '.git' directory

Comment: Running the `del .git\index` will remove the index file if you run it from the root of the working tree in a CMD window.  The alternative in Git Bash is `rm .git/index`.

Comment: I tried to run it in the windows CMD but it says "The system cannot find the file specified." what do you mean with "run it from the root of the working tree" how I do that?

Comment: You have to use `cd` to change into the topmost directory of your repository (the one that has the `.git` directory in it) before running it.

Comment: just run "cd" in the CMD window to go the topmost directory? cause I did it and nothing happens

Comment: No, you have to use `cd` and the name of the topmost directory, such as `cd c:\projects\foo`.

Comment: thanks, that helps

Answer (score 18):

**problem**: bad signature 0x00000000

solved this error in just 2 commands:

1. rm -f .git/index
2. git reset

Comment: i wiped all uncommited changes, thanks

Comment: for me only worked without the '-f', as in:

rm .git/index
git reset
git pull

Answer (score 3):

If you're using git worktrees, the steps wont work, as the file isn't located at .git/index. It's located in the parent repo, at ./git/worktrees/[child name]/index. Delete that file.

Comment: Thanks so much, that saved me from having to rebuild all my worktrees.

Comment: I'm not using worktrees but submodules and this worked for me.
./git/modules/[module path]/index.

Answer (score 1):

Might to erase a folder on PC, clone the project from GitHub and it solved me. Git log also has been restored in this way.